# How can I create a factory method in scala that returns a class whose generic parameter is constrained to be a ClassManifest?

Tags: scala, generics, manifest

I'm trying to write a factory method that returns Foo[T: ClassManifest] (which I need due to the requirements of the library to which I am passing the result) without knowing specifically what T is.  My code is equivalent to:

```
class Foo[T: ClassManifest] (t: T) {
  def getValue: T = t

  override def toString: String = "Foo["+t+": "+t.getClass().getName()+"]"
}

object FooFactory {
  def parse (value: String): Foo[_] = {
    val rest = value.substring(1)
    value.head match {
      case 's' => new Foo[String](rest)
      case 'i' => new Foo[Int](rest.trim.toInt)
      case 'd' => new Foo[Double](rest.trim.toDouble)
    }
  }
}


class FactoryTestSuite extends FunSuite {
  def printIt [T: ClassManifest] (t: Foo[T]): Unit =
    println(t)

  test("Creation") {
    printIt(FooFactory.parse("sabc"))
    printIt(FooFactory.parse("i123"))
    printIt(FooFactory.parse("d1.23"))
  }
}
```

This won't compile - each of the creation test lines complain that it `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type ClassManifest[_$1]`

Is there any way to do this?  Or do the compile-time requirements for ClassManifest make this simply impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result type of `parse` is `Foo[_]`, so `T` is unknown. You can't get `ClassManifest` for unknown type. Just remove `ClassManifest` (and `T`) from `printIt`:

```
def printIt(t: Foo[_]): Unit = println(t)

printIt(FooFactory.parse("sabc"))
// Foo[abc: java.lang.String]

printIt(FooFactory.parse("i123"))
// Foo[123: java.lang.Integer]

printIt(FooFactory.parse("d1.23"))
// Foo[1.23: java.lang.Double]
```

Implicit parameter of type `ClassManifest[T]` of `Foo` constructor is resolved here:

```
case 's' => new Foo[String](rest)
```

Compiler knows that `T` here is `String`. It can create an implicit argument of type `ClassManifest[String]`.

To get `ClassManifest` in method `printIt` you could add it as field in class `Foo`:

```
class Foo[T: ClassManifest] (t: T) {
  val manifest = implicitly[ClassManifest[T]]
  ...
}

def printIt (t: Foo[_]): Unit =
  println(s"t=$t, manifest=${t.manifest}")
```

Comment: @NathanKronenfeld: I guess natural way is to add it as field of `Foo`. See update.

Comment: when I add `val manifest = implicitly[ClassManifest[T]]` to `Foo`, it doesn't seem to make any difference - I get the exact same error.  If, instead, I try your second approach, and pass back the class manifest separately, I don't seem how the class manifest and the real return values will be tied together - the compiler won't know it's a class manifest of the correct type, will it?

Comment: Ah, I got the manifest part to work, through a bit of indirection.  I added a new method to the test, `def tryIt [T] (t: Foo[T]): Unit = printIt(t)(t.manifest)`.  For some reason, the compiler won't find the manifest itself, and if I try to put it in manually in my main function (`val t = FooFactory.parse("sabc");printIt(t)(t.manifest)`), I get an error `found: ClassManifest[(some other)_$1....], required: ClassManifest[_$1...]`

Comment: printIt is the one place I **do** need ClassManifest - it is a library function over which I have no control, so I can't take it out.

Comment: @NathanKronenfeld: with `val t = FooFactory.parse("sabc");printIt(t)(t.manifest)` compiler can't prove that type parameter of `t` (type `Foo[_]`) and `t.manifest` (type `ClassManifest[_]`) is the same (in general `_` != `_`). Maybe it's a bug. You could help to compiler: with method `tryIt[T]` compiler can prove that type parameters are the same (`T` == `T`).